# Tracking which LiDAR data tiles have been delivered?

Tags: tiles, lidar, metadata, cad, data-management

My company works with LiDAR data for large electrical transmissions systems (thousands of miles in one project).  We model the transmission lines and do analysis using CAD and GIS workflows.  We break the system into lines or circuits (1-150 miles each) in order to process the data in smaller units. The LiDAR data itself is broken up into blocks (less than 1sq mile). We always struggle with tracking which blocks have been delivered and which lines are ready for the next step in our workflow.

We are less concerned with signaling when a process is complete and more concerned with determining if all of the necessary raw LiDAR data has been delivered from our collection partner. I know there are all sorts of business intelligence software platforms out there for managing workflows and documents and other contents, but I'm curious if anyone knows of an existing platform for managing lots of raw input data related to the workflow.

Do you know of any software platforms out there designed for this particular task? How do they work?

Answer (score 1):

There is the possibility of quickly opening the .las files within a lidar software viewer having inside it a background image covering the study area.

For example, in Fusion LDV it would look like this:

[image]

In the above scene, two tiles are missing (upper left corner and lower right corner).

After visualizing the .las tiles in the scene, make sure the names of such files be meaningful. For example, grid the background image and name the .las tiles according to the pixel(s) they are part of.

---

In the ArcGIS platform, a similar idea is the [LAS dataset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_LAS_dataset/015w00000057000000/) data type. According to their help page, one advantage of using las datasets is exactly monitoring the coverage of data:

> Conduct initial QA\QC, such as [assessing data coverage and point sample density](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Assessing_lidar_coverage_and_sample_density/015w0000003t000000/), for newly acquired lidar data.