# Displaying pointcloud symbolized with RGB values in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, lidar, 3d, visualisation

I know that I can display a LAS dataset in ArcScene with RGB Symbology, but is there a way of doing this in the 3D View window in ArcMap? The LAS Dataset toolbar only has symbology for elevation, class and return. Why is intensity and RGB not available to select like in ArcScene?

I am using ArcMap (version 10.6.1) which includes a 3D MapViewer with the LAS Toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible yet to symbolize points in RGB and Intensity from the [LAS dataset 3D View](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/las-dataset/las-dataset-3d-view.htm) in **ArcMap**, while in ArcScene one can (ArcScene addressed in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232021/displaying-lidar-data-with-rgb-values-in-arcgis-desktop/232955#232955) post). The controls for symbolizing points in the 3D view are the ones available in the LAS Dataset toolbar:

> The 3D view is only available from the LAS Dataset toolbar in ArcMap.

This is very clear in the [LAS Dataset toolbar - point display options](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/las-dataset/point-display-options.htm) section:

[image]

Why is ArcMap currently more limited than ArcScene I don't know, but if I had to guess I would say this is a work in progress. Surely, the best thing to do is to ask directly to Esri and/or open a feature-request on their side.