# Creating coverage file (vector) from raster data and indexing it to original files?

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector, extents

I have a large number of LiDAR files (in .asc format) that I'm wanting to catalogue so it is easier for people to find the files they want.

How can I take LiDAR files I have, and create a .shp file (ideally polygons) of the areas covered.

My end goal is to have a .shp file people can open on top of a map, check whether or not their location has been covered by LiDAR and then identify the file name that they're after.

Comment: Please add more details about what you want to achieve (maybe adding some screenshots to illustrate: i) what you have and ii) what the final goal would be) and tell us what you have tried. Provide a reproducible example if you expect answers using code to automate the process. Basically, you need a background image of AOI, then generate shapefile using the rasters' bounding box and passing the file names to the shapefiles' TOCs. But this is a long shot, so you need to clarify and narrow your question.

Comment: [This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16381/tracking-which-lidar-data-tiles-have-been-delivered/130227#130227) is a related question, but with actual LiDAR data. What you have is raster data, maybe easier to work than point data (see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207198/interpreting-asc-lidar-data/207767#207767)).

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a new shapefile and use trace settings so that as you create shapes it picks up the boundary on the raster fairly easily?

This is probably not the best solution and would be fairly time consuming (depending on the amount of data), but might get the ball rolling.