# Naming conventions for LiDAR files?

Tags: coordinate-system, tiles, lidar, metadata, naming-conventions

I can't figure out what is specifically being referenced by the names of these .las files:

[image]

They correspond to a specific quadrangle, but can't figure out quite how.

Comment: It appears to be Latitiude (41), Longitude(121) then possibly Group or Grid (g), Group or Grid Number (31), then Tile Number (01 through 25).

That would be my best guess.

Comment: Please do not post images of text, but instead the text itself. That makes the contents both searchable and legible on all devices.

Comment: A final tile index shapefile with the naming convention can be found [here](ftp://lidar.engr.oregonstate.edu/disk1/OLC_KLAMATH_2010/KLAMATH_BUREAUofREC/Vectors/Vectors_Shapefiles/).  @jbgramm is correct

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, especially you @barbarossa! I'm still so green I don't even really understand what I'm looking for/at!

Answer (score 3):

> I'm still so green I don't even really understand what I'm looking for/at!

When working with LiDAR data (and also with other types of GIS data) always seek for metadata information before doing any inspection or processing of the point cloud. It is not always one will have such a nice description like the dataset you are working with.  The **metadata** can be found in:

```
ftp://lidar.engr.oregonstate.edu/disk1/OLC_KLAMATH_2010/KLAMATH_BUREAUofREC/Reports/
```

Let's take the 'Delivery 2' as example. From Table 1 in `KBOR_Delivery_2_LiDAR_report.pdf` you already get a good hint that first five digits in the .las file names are indeed 'latitude' and 'longitude' as [pointed out by jbgramm](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287213/what-naming-convention-is-being-used-here#comment460163_287213).

The other digits are the respective tiles' IDs in the grid which represents the surveyed/scanned scene. You can visualize that by accessing `KBOR_Delivery2_Final_LiDAR_index.shp` (and respective shapefile files) in:

```
ftp://lidar.engr.oregonstate.edu/disk1/OLC_KLAMATH_2010/KLAMATH_BUREAUofREC/Vectors/Vectors_Shapefiles/
```

Example (`41121h5212.las`):

[image]

[image]

'Indexing' LiDAR filenames to their corresponding tile in a grid scene is a best practice for facilitating finding (working with) data subsets. This issue was also addressed in [Tracking which LiDAR data tiles have been delivered](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16381/tracking-which-lidar-data-tiles-have-been-delivered/130227#130227).